# How to return parameterised class in a method?

Tags: java, generics, methods, return, return-type

I have the following method where T is a particular class,

```
public Class<List<T>> responseClass();
```

While implementing this method, how should I return class of `List<T>` ?

Comment: You can't due to type erasure

Comment: What do you intend to do? What is the underlying problem you try to solve here?

Comment: @Lino you could using TypeTokens, for example

Comment: @Eugene only works though if you know `T`. I think jackson has the same with `ParameterizedTypeReference`. Also it can't be done in a complete generic context, like a generic method

Comment: @Lino right. you could return a `Type` instead, though.

Comment: @Lino it’s technically possible to capture a type parameter like `T`, the same way these type tokens work. But it wouldn’t be useful for anything.

Comment: @Holger from what I tried it just returns a `Type T` which is at most useful, to print the name of the type (which would still be only `T`)

Comment: @Lino well, it’s possible to match it with the declaration site, i.e. since it is not declared at the method in this example, it must be declared at a surrounding entity. However, the typical intention of being able to tell whether a particular object is of that type or to construct compatible instances, is not possible. At least not without another type token describing the parameterization of the surrounding entity that declared `T`.